# How to disable the display of duplicate image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is the script that collects all images uploaded to the page from wordpress admin panel and puts them in the slider.

```
<div id="slider-box">
  <div id="current">

  </div>
  <div id="all-photos">

  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
function setCurrent(first) {
    $('#current').html(first);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    // set images to preview and remove big images
    $('#content').find('img').each(function () {

        var photoSrc = $(this).attr('src'),
            photoImg = '<img src="' + photoSrc + '">';

        $('#all-photos').append('<div class="photo-template">' + photoImg + '</div>');
        $(this).remove();
    }); // end each


    // set first image preview to current box 
    var firstPhoto = $('#all-photos').find('div.photo-template:first').html()
    setCurrent(firstPhoto);

    // click handler
    $('div.photo-template').on('click', function () {
        var selected = $(this).html();
        setCurrent(selected);
    });
});
```

It works well, when I add few photos to a page (example http://beardhouse.com.ua/knizhka-divan/millenium), but when I add only one photo - it duplicates in to the box whith small images(example http://beardhouse.com.ua/beskarkasnue-mjagkie-divany/lado) 
How to disable the display of duplicated image when it is only one image published on a page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to you Javascript, it should find the number of images in the bottom and then if it finds that there is more than 1, it will remove the container.

```
if($('#all-photos .photo-template img').length < 2) {
    $('#all-photos').hide();
}
```

Hope this helps.